# qml local import: either highlited, or works

Tags: qt, import, qml, local, highlight

I had problem when I tried to import local directory qml files( they are in the another prefix in qml.qrc)

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import "Components"
//import "qrc:/Components/QMLs/Components"

Rectangle {
    id: mainLocalRect
    width: 300
    height: 500
    color: "orange"

    HIcon {
        id: hIcon
        x: 0
        y: 0
    }
}
```

So that, I got error when deploying:

```
qrc:/QMLs/welcome.qml:4:1: "Components": no such directory
```

but there is directory Components and in Qt Creator HIcon is highlighted.

https://yadi.sk/i/eF1QKfxEhsdiY

I tried another way to import:

```
import "qrc:/Components/QMLs/Components"
```

And its works! But now SideMenu is not highlighted

https://yadi.sk/i/jmdgDZ4dhsdix

Structure of files in project:

```
main.qml
--QMLs/
----class.qml
----welcome.qml
....
----Components/
------HIcon.qml
```

Question: How to correctly to import directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why highlighting does not work when using the correct qrc import is that QtCreator does not inspect the qrc file.

In addition you have to know how the resource system packages the files. Every file will be packaged with it's relative path to your .qrc file:

`main.qml` -> `qrc:///main.qml`
`QMLs/welcome.qml` -> `qrc:///QMLs/welcome.qml`

When using prefixes in your resource files those will be prepended to the relative path. (It's not that Qt 'copies' that file into the specified prefix/folder)
In your project that leads to the following situation:

`QMLs/Components/SideMenu.qml` -> `qrc:///Components/QMLs/Components/SideMenu.qml`
`QMLs/Components/Helpers/MenuBackIcon.qml` -> `qrc:///Helpers/QMLs/Components/Helpers/MenuBackIcon.qml`

It's not only a change in the absolute URL. It also 'moves' the files in the position relative to each other.

Now, to make things better you can specify an alies for each file in your .qrc file. An alias can just be a file name that will be combined with the prefix to make up the full URL:

Let's say you give the alias `HIcon` for your file `QMLs/Components/HIcon.qml`. That will lead to the situation that the full URL will be: `qrc:///Components/HIcon.qml`

Because your .qrc file is in the list of import paths you can now write your code like you'd expect:

```
import "Components"
[..]
    HIcon {
       [..]
    }
```

#### Conclusion / TL;DR

Give each file an alias that is made up of the files name without the path.

Comment: I solved problem!
The solution is put all qml files in one qrc prefix, then in .pro file add all QML files as "OTHER_FILES"
and then it's correctly imports with highlighting.
So all qml files will be in QML, like in this screenshot
https://yadi.sk/i/7LHuUcKmrufjA

Answer (score 1):

You can use simply:

```
import "rel_path"
```

Where `rel_path` is the relative path from the point of view of the file that contains the import statement.

As an example, if the component `C` is in a child directory called `D` for the parent one, use:

```
import "../D/"
```

From now on, you can freely use `C` within your file.

Comment: importing with rel_path is not actual, because project is under the VCS, so that in another computer(work station) may not works